# Textmate 2: Edit Each Line in Selection

Tags: macos, textmate

Textmate used to allow selecting multiple lines and doing <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to add text to the end of each line.

This no longer seems to work in Textmate 2.

Any ideas if this feature still works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select all the lines you want to edit.
2. Turn it into a column selection (<kbd>⌥</kbd>).
3. Then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to move all the carets to the end of each line.

The answer was found at [Textmate 2 Tips](http://tm2tips.tumblr.com/post/14387239866/replicating-edit-each-line-in-selection).

Alternatively to steps 1 and 2, you can make the original selection by holding down the option key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) while making the selection with the mouse.